# jQuery, format date doesn't showing the right format

Tags: jquery, date-format

I'd like to display the date of the first day of the selected month but the format of date doesn't showing me the right format.

I'd like to show it like this **01/11/2017** but it is displayed like this

> Wed Nov 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

```
Select a Date: <input type="date" id="theDate" onmouseout="getTheDays()"/>
<p>First Day of the Month: <label id="fday"></label></p>
<p>Last Day of the Month: <label id="lday"></label></p>

<script>
    function getTheDays() {

        var dt = new Date($('#theDate').val());

        // GET THE MONTH AND YEAR OF THE SELECTED DATE.
        var month = dt.getMonth(),
            year = dt.getFullYear();

        // GET THE FIRST AND LAST DATE OF THE MONTH.
        var FirstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
        var LastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);

        // FINALLY, GET THE DAY.
        var weekday = new Array();
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";


        if (typeof weekday[FirstDay.getDay()] != 'undefined') {     // CHECK FOR 'undefined'.
            $('#fday').html(FirstDay.toString('dd-MM-yy'));
        }
        else {
            $('#fday').text('');
            $('#lday').text('');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Jacob gave you a great answer, but you should know that there are no parameters to any of the "toString" type methods of a date object. That was your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I share with you our `toShortDate` function, here you are:

```
function toShortDate(date) {
    if (!date) {
        return '--/--/--';
    }
    var d = new Date(Date.parse(date)),
        days = d.getDate(),
        month = (d.getMonth() + 1),
        finalDays = days < 10 ? '0' + days : '' + days,
        finalMonth = month < 10 ? '0' + month : '' + month;

    return finalDays +
        "/" + finalMonth +
        "/" + d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);
}
```

This function has been working in production for a while now and it works perfectly. Good luck.

Comment: If you're browsing the internet trying to find a date formating function, be aware that this javascript cannot be used reliably if the timezone is a factor. For instance, if you run this on CodePen you'll most assuredly (unless you live in the same timezone as CodePen) end up with a date object in a different timezone. In my case, and due to the current time of day, the formatted dates are formatted a day behind what I pick.

Comment: That is true, thank you for your note. This code doesn't handle timezone differences. It just format the date it get as parameter (as requested in this question). However, our application is multi-cultured, but the time-zone conversion made by the middle layer between the server (WebAPI) and the JavaScript. I think most applications work in this way (or should do at least) like this build in function in WebAPI and "data to JSON" conversion.